# Cant get square to display properly, using index buffers, in Vulkan

Tags: graphics, vulkan

I am currently trying to learn vulkan. I am using [vulkan-tutorial.com](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Vertex_buffers/Index_buffer), but am having som problems getting the same result as the tutorial. When the tutorial is creating a square, using [index buffers](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Vertex_buffers/Index_buffer), they get a square, while I get a triangle. I copied the code they posted (on [the page](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Vertex_buffers/Index_buffer)) into my project to make shure I did not write somehting wrong

Here is a image of what I am rendering
[image: Thsi is the "square" I am rendering]

While this is what I should be rendering
[image: Square renderd from Vulkan-tutorial.com]

All the code I am using is found on the [page](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Vertex_buffers/Index_buffer), or here:
[c++ code](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/code/20_index_buffer.cpp), [vertex shader](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/code/17_shader_vertexbuffer.vert), [fragment shader](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/code/17_shader_vertexbuffer.frag)

If you need more info about anything, just ask.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Recompile your shaders (double check them, iirc vulkan-tutorial uses shader constants for previous basic example), and double check your vertices: the positions on your screen are definetly from some old part with only a triangle

Comment: Are you using 100% the vulkan-tutorial's code or are there some parts of your own? If the former is the case, I could imagine that you are maybe using old versions of your SPIR-V shaders.

Comment: I have copied all of the code form the webpage. I have recompiled the shaders. nothing worked. I did try to make the shader take in a vec3 insted of a vec2, and that resulted in the rest of that triangle beeing rendred (so now i have a full triangle out of 2 triangles).